# SharePoint 2013 Document Management For Large Size

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I have a requirement in which I have to maintain `400 clients documents` and data in SharePoint and all documents size would be `200 GB` near around.Is this application is suitable for SharePoint 2013? I need to draw and architecture.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you start reading MSDN articles. Start with [THIS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ff758645.aspx) and [THIS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx)

If the whole solution will be split across multiple content databases, lists and libraries will be created with a sense of mind, and everything will be governed properly, then I don't see a problem with 200GB and 400 clients.

Comment: With this requirement can we go with office 365?

Comment: Yes. Database limits in 365 are different. 1 TB per site collection. See https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/SharePoint-Online-software-boundaries-and-limits-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498

Answer (score 0):

couple of things which should be consider:

**Number Of items:** this thing is important when you are talking about the large number of items. if you have more than 5,000 items, then LIST View Threshold will be cause the issue if you dont plan it properly. please check [How do I handle the large List with more than 5K items in SharePoint 2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105472/how-do-i-handle-the-large-list-with-more-than-5k-items-in-sharepoint-2010). This thing is apply to both on **SharePoint on-prem** as well as **SharePoint Online**.

**Size of content**: this one is not really big issue now a days, as SharePoint content db can go upto **4TB** and SPO 1TB. But key over here is if you are using SPO then you dont need to worry about the back end( backup and recovery) But on-prem environment, you have to plan it accordingly. If one site collection with more than 200GB in single Content DB will not issue but multiple large site collection in a single db will delay the recovery.

**Choices you have**:

- You can go SPO, it will be cost effective and now extra hardware required. ready to use. No need to worry about the updates and patching, licensing etc. if you have less number of user then i highly recommend it.
- In case of on-prem SharePoint installation, you need a dedicated resource for managing the SharePoint, you need the hardware as well as software( license) for you environment, then you have to perform the upgrades on the farm etc. for small I dont recommend it.