# SPList performance issue

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, splist, item

I am having a SPList with some 500 records/items in it.

My visual web part used to read this SPList whenever the page loads and the SPList was populated by a timer job on a daily basis. The customer says that, after 6 months the data in the SPList increase dramatically.

How do I handle this kind of situation? If the number of items in a SPList is in the millions, how do I performance tune this SPList? If its document library, I can create folders and push the information into the folders and sub-folders but can we create folders in SPList? Or any other approaches are available for handling millions of items in a SPList?

Comment: take a look here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105472/how-do-i-handle-the-large-list-with-more-than-5k-items-in-sharepoint-2010

Comment: You can add folders to lists yes

Comment: Could you paste the code you are using to retrieve teh items?

Comment: You can´t do very much on the list itself. It mainly depends on your architecture, how you Access the list in your web part. All you could do is create an indexed column in the list, which you can use for your where-statement (hopefully you have any). As jpussacq said, pls poste your code

Comment: if the list goes into millions, consider the Maximum amount of 30.000.000 items per list (depending also on usage and columns, but not more than 30.000.000)

Comment: @NkSP Regarding the link that you pasted, even though I've seen this so many times, I still don't understand how it is still believed that that a list view only requests 30 items per page and so it should be fine. I have a list with 20000 items in it and displaying a view without filtering shows me the threshold error. Weird...

Comment: @ueberz91 You are wrong. if you do not have a filter, it requests ALL items, orders it (if any) and Shows (delivers) 30 items (which block depends on the current page). eg, if you are on the second page, it reqests all items from database, orders it and Shows only the items 31 to 60. So, because you request more items than the treshold, you´ll get the error

Comment: @LeopoldLerch right I'm aware of that. Was just confused about the highest upvoted answer in NkSPs link which clearly states that list views request only 30 without modification. What do you think about that?