# How to get more than 5000 items in list without enabled throttling?

Tags: splistitem, large-lists, resource-throttling

I'm trying to work with large list but every time I do an operation on a list I have an exception because I have more than 5000 items in my list.

`Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQueryThrottledException`

If I do this code I have the exception. 
`sPList1.Folders.Count`

How can I work with large list without enabled throttling?

EDIT:
I don't understand how to use the query to check if there are folders:

```
query.QueryThrottleMode = SPQueryThrottleOption.Override;
```

My exception is thrown when i do:

```
if (sPList1.Folders.Count <= 0)
```

Here is the exception when I attempt to perform an action:

```
        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.QueryThrottleMode = SPQueryThrottleOption.Override;//execute query in admin and bypass throttling
query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /><Value Type='Integer'>1</Value></Eq></Where>";//caml to count folder
SPListItemCollection listitem = null;
listitem = sPList1.GetItems(query);
```

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105472/how-do-i-handle-the-large-list-with-more-than-5k-items-in-sharepoint-2010

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
query.QueryThrottleMode = SPQueryThrottleOption.Override;
```

by executing the query as a super user.

[SharePoint 2010 List Throtelling](http://adicodes.com/sharepoint-2010-list-throtelling/)

Try the following code to get the items based on the folder,

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite("site url"))
{
  using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
  {
    SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder("/Docs/folder1");
    if(folder.ItemCount > 0)
    {
      SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("ListName");
      SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
      query.Folder = folder;
      SPListItemCollection listitem = list.GetItems(query);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is above solution works for you?

Comment: Thanks for your solution but with this how can i check if list has folder

Comment: it is just overriding the threshold problems querying the list.

Comment: Did you still get an error?

Comment: yes because i don't understand how to use camlquery to check if splist has folders

Comment: I had added the sample code to get folder from SPlist. Please check it

Comment: Thanks for your sample but i have to check if splist has folder to build a treeview. If it has i show the folder name. In your exemple you know the folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the items in pages, 
in one page will be 5000 items, and if it is not the last page, you have a pointer to the next page. Finally put the query to a do-while loop.
This code works for me in powershell, but in C# it will be similar.

```
$Ids = @()
$list = $rootWeb.Lists.GetByTitle($listName)
$qCommand = @"
<View Scope='RecursiveAll' >
<Query>
  <Where>
  </Where>
</Query>
<RowLimit Paged="True">5000</RowLimit>
<QueryOptions>
    <ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll' />
</QueryOptions>
</View>
"@

$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$query.ViewXml = $qCommand

$ctx.Load($list)
$ctx.Load($list.RootFolder)

do 
{
    $listItems = $list.GetItems($query)
    $ctx.Load($listItems)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    $query.ListItemCollectionPosition = $listItems.ListItemCollectionPosition

$i = 0
foreach ($item in $listItems)
{
    if ($item["TaskStatus"] -eq "Nezačaté" -and $item["PosielatUpozornenia"] -ne $false)
    {
       $Ids += $item.Id
    } 
}
}
 while ($query.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)
 echo $Ids.Count
```